# Is it possible to have dynamic App icon in Android?

Tags: android-widget, android-appwidget, android-launcher, android-icons

Is it possible to have dynamic App icon in Android? For example let's say I have clock App. Can I update the App icon showing current time or is the only way to implement a widgets?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `<activity-alias>` to display different app icons in the launcher, just like the example I created [here](https://github.com/Katecca/android-dynamic-app-icon)

But I don't think it is a good decision to update the app icon per minute, the solution may only applicable to calendar app.